# How do I just extract the second component of a Python array?

Tags: python

E.g.

```
training_set
[((1, 0, 0), 1), ((1, 0, 1), 1), ((1, 1, 0), 1), ((1, 1, 1), 0), [(1, 1, 10), 1]]
```

How can I just extract the second part of each matrix within the array? Just the 1,1,1,0,1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use map:

```
>>> training_set=[((1, 0, 0), 1), ((1, 0, 1), 1), ((1, 1, 0), 1), ((1, 1, 1), 0), [(1, 1, 10), 1]]
>>> map(lambda t: t[-1], training_set)
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

As stated in the comments:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> item=itemgetter(-1)
>>> map(item, training_set)
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

And:

```
>>> zip(*training_set)[1]
(1, 1, 1, 0, 1)
```

Comment: Or, for fun, `operator.itemgetter(-1)` instead of the lambda.

Comment: or, `zip(*training_set)[1]` ... O man... :-)

Answer (score 12):

List comprehension:

```
[d[1] for d in training_set]
```